# MySQL trigger: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger that monitor changes on a table and then insert those change to another table as follows

```
CREATE TRIGGER userChangePasswd
BEFORE UPDATE ON originalTable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO logs (email,clear,name ) SELECT email,clear,name FROM  originalTable
END
```

mysql keeps showing the following error

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO logs (email,clear,name ) SELECT email,clear,name FROM ' originalTable at line 5
```

the following statement works very file with a where clause criteria

```
INSERT INTO logs (email,clear,name ) SELECT email,clear,name FROM  originalTable
```

what's wrong with the insertion statement within the trigger

Comment: are you using a version higher than 5.0.10 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER `orgTbl_before_upd_tr` BEFORE UPDATE ON `orgTbl`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO newTbl (field1, field2) VALUES (old.field1, old.field2);
END;
```